# Friendly URL Structure with folders

Tags: url, seo, structure, building

I am currently building the URL Structure for an insurance website. I was hoping someone would give me some advice? I am trying to make it as SEO friendly as possible!

As an example, for 'travel insurance' the URL link would be;

http://www.example.com**/travel_insurance/travel.html**

and then for the quote form;

http://www.example.com**/travel_insurance/quote/get_a_quote.html**

would that be an ideal structure?

Any suggestions/advice is appreciated!

Comment: Please use `example.com` for your example domain, not `website.com` (which is owned by someone, probably not being you).

Answer (score 4):

Being an seo specialist, it is best practice to keep your URL's as short and descriptive as possible.
If you want the actual page to rank online then add the keywords you wish to rank for in the URL.
If you do not want the page to rank it won't matter much. 
Too many characters in the URL will not show up fully in search engine results snippets and can cuase a loss of potential clicks thru to your web page.

It is also best procatices to use a - Dash rather than _ underscore in your URL's.

I would go with:

http://www.website.com/travel-insurance.html

http://www.website.com/travel-insurance/get-a-quote.html

Less folders, quicker path, easier to understand.

Comment: do you think `.html` is necessary? Or are there no differences between URLs with this ending or not?